# SelectOneRadio set checked on radioButton

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I want to set the state checked on a p:selectOneRadio using javascript.

I manage to do it but it only works with the first elemt on the selectOneRadio list here's the code.

```
<h:form id="formID">
    <p:outputPanel id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{radioView.color}" layout="custom">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Red" itemValue="Red" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Green" itemValue="Green" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Blue" itemValue="Blue" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" border="1">
            <p:radioButton id="opt1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0" />
            <h:outputLabel for="opt1" value="Red" />

            <p:radioButton id="opt2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1" />
            <h:outputLabel for="opt2" value="Green" />

            <p:radioButton id="opt3" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2" />
            <h:outputLabel for="opt3" value="Blue" />

            <p:commandButton value="select" ajax="true" onclick="selectRadios()" update="@form"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectRadios() {
        jQuery("input[name='formID:customRadio']:first").prop('checked', true);
    }
    ;
</script>
```

As I load the page and click on the commandButton it checked the first radiobutton and its fine but I also want to know how to check the other two.

Also if there is other way that can change the state to cheked of that radiobutton without using javascript pls let me know.

Thanks for the help.

-Keva

Comment: Which HTML pre-processor do you use? Can you post the produced HTML please?

Comment: Are you trying to select all of the radio boxes? If Yes, you're using SelectOneRadio that can only select one item on the list.

Comment: @MarkVincentOsea Im no trying to select all. All I want is the code to select one radio button as I click the commandbutton. As you can see I manage to do it but just for the first radio button (first of three) how can I do it for the sencond one or the third one

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette what do you mean by HTML pre-processor?

Comment: I mean this HTML coding syntax `<[tagname]:[type ? ] [attributes]>`... It's not plain HTML. A "pre-processor" is used to interpret it. I don't know which... There's plenty. So if you can post the "real" HTML, it would help.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Im using html powerd by PrimeFaces and I dont know if im getting what you're asking here es the html tag im using

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">`

Comment: `Doctype` is irrelevant. But I just focussed on the `Primefaces` keyword, which I didn't cared of till now (My bad). It looks like it is a «JSF component suite with various extensions» [Reference, p. 10/634](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf). **I won't read it**. To provide plain HTML to your question, [*which you can edit*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40228439/edit), You'll need to copy/paste relevant source of the page you're testing. It can be viewed by adding **`view-source:`** right before the URL... In Chrome... (don't know for other browsers).

Comment: There is an HTML editor in that «suite»... That's what I meant with *HTML pre-processor*. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made a second effort to ...*see*... your HTML.

The HTML result of your *«[Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) included editor»* is sure close to what I'm posting now in below snippet. *(Quite simple, after the syntax barrier)*

So have a look at the jQuery code...
It should be close to your main concern.

**Your question#1:** *«As I load the page and click on the commandButton it checked the first radiobutton and its fine but I also want to know how to check the other two»*

→ It's the *nature* of a radio buttons to be exclusive within a group.
     Look for checkboxes if you want many checked.

**Your question#2:** *«Also if there is other way that can change the state to cheked of that radiobutton without using javascript pls let me know.»*

→ Yes... Onload.
     Via an [HTML `checked` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_checked.asp)

  ELSE
→ No.

**BONUS**
I added console.log to it on any state change (make by user) for `select` and `radio`s.

```js
var radioCollection = $("input[name='myRadio']");

var radioCheckedVal = 0;  // 0 is first element in zero-based collection.
                          // Change to make another radio selected onload.

// 1st radio input is selected onload
$(radioCollection).first().prop('checked', true);

$(radioCollection).click(function(){
    if( $(this).is("input:checked") ){
        radioCheckedVal = $(this).val();
        console.log( "Radio input checked: "+radioCheckedVal );
    }
});

$("#customPanel").change(function(){
    selectVal = $(this).val();
    console.log( "Dropdown selected: "+selectVal );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formID">
  <select id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px"><!-- p:outputPanel ?? -->
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="opt1" value="Red">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="opt1">Red</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="opt2" value="Green">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="opt1">Green</labe2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="opt3" value="Blue">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="opt1">Blue</labe3>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```